# pointer/integer type mismatch in conditional expression

Tags: c, ternary-operator

```
gcc 4.7.2 c89
```

Hello,

I am getting the following warning:

```
pointer/integer type mismatch in conditional expression
```

I am compiling with the following `CFLAGS -Wall -Wextra`

```
fprintf(stderr, "'Failed to open file' Error [ %s ]\n",
        (errno == 0) ? "None" : strerror(errno));
```

The program runs ok, but I can't see that the warning is all about. Both "None" and strerror(errno) return a string and not Integer value. And I am comparing errno number to zero.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: No I didn't. I have just included it and the warning went away. Is this because the string.h includes the strerror function. However, if that was the case and I have seen that in the man pages. So shouldn't it give me a compile error? Thanks.

Comment: A long time ago, the C language allowed you to use a function without a declaration. It would then assume that the function returned an `int`. This behavior is now non-standard (because of the consequences you have encountered) but many compilers still accept it for compatibility with older code. I am surprised you did not get a warning (for the function use and not just for the conditional expression) using `-Wall -Wextra` though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check whether you have included `<string.h>` header. If not, the return value of `strerror` may be considered as an integer value. It would explain why the program runs ok (the linker can find a matched function named `strerror`, because the C standard library is linked by default), whereas the compiler reports a warning.