# Why is the use of the conditional operator giving the warning "pointer/integer type mismatch " in my program?

Tags: c, warnings

Here's my program:

```
int main()
{
printf("%d : %s\n", errno, (errno==0)?"no error":strerror(errno));
}
```

It gives this warning upon compilation:

`warning: pointer/integer type mismatch in conditional expression [enabled by default]`

Since `errno` is of type `int` and the expression "no error" and `strerror()` both return a pointer to a string,why am I getting an error?

Comment: See the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13220087/pointer-integer-type-mismatch-in-conditional-expression).

Comment: OP, next time call the `?:` thingie a **conditional operator**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that `#include <string.h>` is not included, which means [`strerror()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strerror) has an implicit function declaration generated for it which returns an `int`.

This code (http://ideone.com/6BckJx):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%d : %s\n", errno, (errno==0)?"no error":strerror(errno));
    return 0;
}
```

produces:

```
prog.c: In function ‘main’:
prog.c:6:5: error: implicit declaration of function ‘strerror’ 
    [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
prog.c:6:53: error: pointer/integer type mismatch in conditional expression
    [-Werror]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

Adding `#include <string.h>` corrects the problem (http://ideone.com/Ihycd0).